# How to support multiple, mutually exclusive parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-7.3, parameter-sets

I must write a script to get instances of Thing.
Each Thing contains an event timestamp.
I need to allow the user to specify a timestamp range.

- There are four (4) time-specifying parameters
- None are mandatory
- $Since and $StartTimestamp are mutually exclusive
- $Until and $EndTimestamp are mutually exclusive
- The script will translate $Since and $Until strings into an appropriate [datetime]

How can I use a ParameterSet to disable the use of both $Since and $StartTimestamp
AND disable the use of both $Until and $EndTimestamp?

Posts about using multiple ParameterSets appear to grow exponentially with the number of parameters. Is this really the way?

There are posts about using a DynamicParam. I do not yet see where a DynamicParam would be appropriate for this. Is it?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ThingName

    ,[ValidateSet('Today', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek')]
    [string] $Since

    ,[datetime] $StartTimestamp

    ,[ValidateSet('Today', 'Now', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek')]
    [string] $Until

    ,[datetime] $EndTimestamp
)
```

Comment: Yes, parameter sets would grow exponentially. DynamicParam seems like overkill. I would question the use of two separate parameters for what is logically one parameter that allows for specifying a time in different formats. You could use a single parameter of type `object` that accepts both a `string` and a `datetime` and cast the type in the body of the function. Validation could be done using `ValidateScript`.

Comment: @zett42 - I wanted to have the "word" parameters in order to provide tab-completion for the -Since and -Until parameters. Is it possible to do that if the parameter type is `object`?

Comment: @lit, combine zett42's `ValidateScript` suggestion with an `ArgumentCompleter` attribute: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204718/45375) for an example (it uses `[string]`, but `[object]` should work too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Mutually exclusive* parameters are indeed hard to implement using [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets)**, as of this writing (PowerShell v7.3.4):

- [GitHub issue #5175](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5175) is a long-standing feature request to make defining mutually exclusive parameters easier, but it has
- [GitHub issue #12818](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12818) is a more recent and more comprehensive feature covering other aspects of parameter sets as well.

A solution with the current features is possible, but cumbersome:

Note: I'm assuming that you want to *allow* only the following combinations (this complements the description of what you want to *prevent* in your question), and this *positive* formulation can expressed be via parameter sets:

- `-ThingName` only, or combined with any of the following:
- `-Since` only, `-Until` only
- `-StartTimestamp` only, `-EndTimeStamp` only
- `-Since` combined with `-EndTimeStamp`
- `-Until` combined with `-StartTimeStamp`

```bash
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ThingAlone')]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $ThingName
    ,    
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='SinceAlone')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartSinceEndUntil')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartSinceEndTimestamp')]
    [ValidateSet('Today', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek')]
    [string] $Since
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartTimestampAlone')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartTimestampEndUntil')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartTimestampEndTimestamp')]
    [datetime] $StartTimestamp
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='UntilAlone')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartSinceEndUntil')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartTimestampEndUntil')]
    [ValidateSet('Today', 'Now', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek')]
    [string] $Until
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='EndTimeStampAlone')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartSinceEndTimestamp')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='StartTimestampEndTimestamp')]
    [datetime] $EndTimestamp
)

$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

Resulting syntax diagram (invoke the script with `-?`):

```
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -Since <string> -EndTimestamp <datetime> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -Since <string> -Until <string> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -Since <string> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -StartTimestamp <datetime> -EndTimestamp <datetime> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -StartTimestamp <datetime> -Until <string> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -StartTimestamp <datetime> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -Until <string> [<CommonParameters>]
YourScript.ps1 [-ThingName] <string> -EndTimestamp <datetime> [<CommonParameters>]
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

- As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, you can ***bypass* the need for mutual exclusion** if you **provide only a *single, polymorphous* parameter** for the start and end timestamp, respectively.
- To that end, declare these parameters as `[object]` (so they can accept a value of any type), and:

  - use a `[ValidateScript()]` attribute to ensure that a value passed by the user can either be parsed as a `[datetime]` instance *or* is one of the predefined symbolic names, such as `Today`.
  - In order to also support *tab-completion*, use an `[ArgumentCompleter()]` attribute that completes the symbolic names.
  - Note: The arrays of symbolic names are *duplicated* in the two attributes below:

    - In a stand-alone *script* that cannot be avoided, but in a *function* (e.g. as part of a module) you could define the arrays only once.

```bash
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $ThingName
    ,
    [ArgumentCompleter({
      param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete)
      'Today', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek' -like "$wordToComplete*"
    })]
    [ValidateScript({
      if ($_ -notin 'Today', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek' -and $null -eq ($_ -as [datetime])) {
        throw "Invalid -Since argument."
      }
      $true
    })]
    [object] $Since
    ,
    [ArgumentCompleter({
      param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete)
      'Today', 'Now', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek' -like "$wordToComplete*"
    })]
    [ValidateScript({
      if ($_ -notin 'Today', 'Now', 'Yesterday', 'LastWeek' -and $null -eq ($_ -as [datetime])) {
        throw "Invalid -Until argument."
      }
      $true
    })]
    [object] $Until
)

# Translate the -Since and -Until arguments into [datetime] instances.
$i = 0
$sinceTimestamp, $untilTimestamp = 
    $Since, $Until | ForEach-Object {
      switch ($_) {
        $null { if ($i -eq 0) { Get-Date -Date 0 } else { Get-Date }; break }
        Now { Get-Date; break }
        Today { (Get-Date).Date; break }
        Yesterday  { (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1); break }
        LastWeek  { (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7); break }
        Default { $_ -as [datetime] }
      }
      ++$i
    }
if ($untilTimestamp -lt $sinceTimestamp) { Throw "The -Since argument must predate the -Until argument." }

# Diagnostic output.
[pscustomobject] @{
  Since = $sinceTimestamp
  Until = $untilTimestamp
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 - Many thanks for your great answer (as usual). I have coded both of these up. ParameterSets work, but are, as you say, cumbersome. For the second solution, if -Since is not specified, $SinceTimestamp needs to be the beginning of time. `(Get-Date -Year 1 -Month 1 -Day 1)`? If -Until is not specified, it should be the current time. `(Get-Date)`.

Comment: My pleasure, @lit, and thanks for the nice feedback. I've updated the answer to add the default values: `Get-Date 0` is the simplest way to get the earliest supported timestamp; it is equivalent to `[datetime] 0` and therefore `[datetime]::new(0)`, i.e. you're passing a _ticks_ value of `0`.

Comment: I am -not- asking that you revise the code. This has been most helpful. I may need to make a change. Using `-Since Today` and `-Until Today` probably means `(Get-Date).Date` (midnight) and `(Get-Date)` (now) respectively. Or, perhaps this should just be a documentation issue. `-Until Now` would be more explicit.